# Authorization Header Not Recognized by Nginx Server

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework

I was wondering why my Authorization Header is not recognized. When I pass it to my server web app endpoint.

[image]

However, when I do it on my localhost it works well

[image]

These are my request headers: [image]

**PS.**

I am using Django Rest Framewok on my backend and what you see is Google Chrome's Advanced REST Client for testing my APIs. Also please take note that the **CORS HEADERS are allowed** and **Token Authentication** is the method I'm Using as credentials for my endpoints.

Comment: Please provide nginx conf ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any,, My Hosting Server which is hostnine uses Nginx as I see on my Advanced REST Client, I'm just having a shared hosting with tnem..

Comment: Can you provide request header in your response output. (just  below 401 unauthorized )

Comment: I believe its some other problem as authorization present in request header. Either you didn't create token in the database or any small mistake ?

Comment: It should return an "invalid token" if the token is not present. What happens here is that the authorization header is not being recognized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114994/discussion-between-dean-christian-armada-and-anurag).